# git svn rebase showing ambiguous argument 'HEAD' error

Tags: git, svn

I have my svn repository in this layout:

```
trunk
branches
|--feature
tags
|--project-version1
|--project-version2
```

And i use git svn to create git project like this:

```
git svn clone https://my.svn.repo -T trunk -t tags -b branches
```

After that I tried:

```
git svn rebase
```

And got error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
log --no-color --no-decorate --first-parent --pretty=medium HEAD: command returned error: 128
```

I don't know why i got that error. Can you help me pointing out the error?

Thanks,

Comment: This is weird. The error message means that the git ref "HEAD" does not exist. However, every git repo always must have HEAD - and `git svn clone` creates it automatically. So something is very wrong.

Comment: Please try to reproduce the problem: First, install a current version of git and git-svn (just in case you ran into an old bug). Run the `git svn clone` again. Note any errors it shows. Then check if `.git/HEAD` exists and what it contains. Add that information to your question. Then we'll see...